# Getting the content of <script> element

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I've tried to use innerHTML but it returns null.
Here's my code:

```
var sumScripts = gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("script");
  for (i = 0; i < sumScripts.length; i++) { 
    var content = sumScripts[i].innerHTML;
    alert(content);
```

So I tried to get all the scripts on a webpage and print them, but it prints null each time. Does anyone know what's wrong? This is XUL JavaScript by the way.

EDIT : Silly me. I fixed the iterator typo (changing 0 to i), thanks. It works now.

Comment: null or `""`(empty string).

Comment: You aren't using your iterator. Pretty sure you want to do `var content = sumScripts[i].innerHTML;`. If your first script tag is empty, that would explain it.

Comment: Why are you looping through the scripts, when you only look at the first script entry?? `sumScripts[0].innerHTML` should be `sumScripts[i].innerHTML`

Comment: This should generally work -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/CYp9b/**

Comment: innerHTML should actually work. But only for script tags with content (not for script tags with `src="somewhere.js"` attribute). Compare this [piece of code from ICanHaz](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/ICanHaz.js/blob/master/source/main.js#L75). Can you create a jsfiddle with some of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FF addon priveleaged scope you have a ton available to you.

You can access `Document.scripts`. Read about it here on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

But this is also available to non-priveagled. Just do `window.document.scripts` and itterate.

```
var scripts = gBrowser.contentWindow.document.scripts;
for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, scripts[i].src, scripts[i].innerHTML)
}
```

keep in mind, some script elements have set `src=blah` so they wont have innerHTML. You would have to get that by either live fetch (xmlhttprequest, etc) or cached value.

Comment: I tried to save document.scripts in a variable before, but it doesn't work. Dunno why. Thanks for the info btw, 1 more point before I can upvote lol :p @Noitidart

Comment: Oh that's interesting thanks for sharing that fact. That's odd how you can't store it in var. Are you sure about that? As last resort, do you have to store it in var?

Comment: Tried it in scratchpad, I can store it in content environment, but not in browser environment. I realized you have to use gBrowser in browser environment lol. No, not necessary. @noitidart